# Cleanest way to avoid long code lines with Java8 stream api

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

How should I refactor lines like this?

```
return chars.codePoints().mapToObj(cp->((!Character.UnicodeBlock.SPECIALS.equals(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(cp))) && (! Character.isISOControl(cp)))?"'"+String.valueOf(Character.toChars(cp))+"'":"0x"+Integer.toHexString(cp)).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Should I

- reassign the stream to local variables, to make it just "more vertical", but leave the lambda where it is used
- create a method like `private String codePointToString(int cp) {...}` to shorten the lambda to `cp->codePointToString(cp)`
- create a function constant instead of a method:
  `private static final IntFunction<String> codePointToString = cp->{...};`
  and use it like `mapToObj(codePointToString)`

?

Comment: While both answers suggesting more or less the same, I follow @Holger´s arguments about the function constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing, I would do, is cleaning up the condition by inverting it and removing the obsolete parentheses. As you has written it, I had really trouble to understand it, but thankfully, my IDE offered me to do that automatically. So it became

```
return chars.codePoints().mapToObj(cp->
     Character.UnicodeBlock.SPECIALS.equals(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(cp))
  || Character.isISOControl(cp)?
     "0x"+Integer.toHexString(cp):
     "'"+String.valueOf(Character.toChars(cp))+"'")
  .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

which is far more readable.

Regarding the other options, there is no general rule. You may put either, the condition or the entire conversion method into a method named after its purpose, as that would help the reader even more, and reference it within the expression, e.g.

```
mapToObj(cp->printableCodePoint(cp)?
         "0x"+Integer.toHexString(cp): "'"+String.valueOf(Character.toChars(cp))+"'")
```

or via lambda expression/ method reference, e.g.

```
mapToObj(cp->codePointToString(cp)) or mapToObj(MyClass::codePointToString)
```

I don’t recommend storing a function into a variable like in your third bullet. You can easily create a function from an ordinary method via lambda expression but you can not create an ordinary method out of a function with that ease. And forcing code to call a method via `codePointToStringFunction.apply(cp);` rather than the ordinary `codePointToString(cp);` where no functional operation are involved looks like bad coding style to me. So keeping reusable code in ordinary methods raises its versatileness.

Answer (score 4):

I would indeed extract a method `codePointToString()`, which would make the code easier to read and unit-test. I would also have one step per line:

```
return chars.codePoints()
            .mapToObj(this::codePointToString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

To make the code of the extracted method readable, I would also put space around operators, and use an `if` rather than the ternary operator

```
private String codePointToString(int codePoint) {
   if (!Character.UnicodeBlock.SPECIALS.equals(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(cp)) 
       && !Character.isISOControl(cp)) {
       return "'" + String.valueOf(Character.toChars(cp)) + "'";
    }
    else {
        return "0x" + Integer.toHexString(cp);
    }
}
```